# Cybercrime use of cryptocurrency and stolen goods laws

Tags: theft, cryptocurrency

I've been wondering if this line of reasoning has been tried anywhere in the world, successfully or unsuccessfully. It seems improbable that I'm the first to think of it ...

- A cryptocurrency is a bit of data, recorded in a cryptographically protected [blockchain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blockchain) ledger.
- The Bitcoin ledger is public.
- Despite the name, a Bitcoin is not currency. The exact status varies from jurisdiction to jurisdiction.
- If a criminal obtains an object through theft, the criminal does not have any property rights. Subsequent sales may be void, with different laws as to good faith or statutes of limitations.

So the amateur assumption would be that a victim of cyber-blackmail or hacking could try and identify the *current holder(s) of the bitcoin* through the ledger and demand the return of the stolen property, if necessary by a *civil* lawsuit even if the current holder is not criminally culpable. Bitcoins may be split in transactions, but that can be followed as well.

Doing that on any significant scale might kill the concept of a cryptocurrency, of course, but the victims might not care. At the very least, there would be diligence requirements to ascertain that any one bitcoin is not *tainted* by crime in any significant jurisdiction.

Comment: Bitcoin is not anonymous and you are right that all transactions are public, but with "mixing" services and various truly anonymous cryptocurrencies, it's quite easy to hide the real destination that the money is sent to. Once that money is spent, trying to "track down" the current holders is fruitless as it will be spread everywhere. It's no more likely that you could get anything back from current holders than you would be of getting actual, physical cash back from current holders after it's changed hands so many times.

Comment: @forest Can you not argue that whoever received your bitcoin through the mixer is the current holder? (likewise you received someone else's bitcoin)

Comment: @user253751, the problem would be that 100 people hold one percent of that bitcoin, each. Finding them and filing the lawsuit is less practical than finding one.

Comment: @o.m. That wasn't the question, was it? I believe the question was whether or not it was possible. But the question wasn't clear.

Comment: @user253751, the question is more if it happens and if not, why not. "Not worth the effort *in practice* even if it could be done *in theory*" would be a valid answer, if it was indeed the answer. No sane person sues to recover $1, unless the point is to make a point.

Comment: @user253751 You'd be suing someone to recover less than $1 at a time. You might potentially have to sue _thousands_ of people or more due to block fees.